# Can I add a JIRA ticket from one project to a sprint from another project?

Tags: plugins, jira, agile, sprint, jira-agile

JIRA's Agile screen lets me take all the tickets in one project; and drag them to the sprint.

However, I don't see any way to add a ticket from a different project to that sprint.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

Boards can include issues from multiple projects if the board is configured to look at them.

To do this, you will need to [edit the board filter](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Filters) to include another project.

In JIRA Agile 6.x, you do this by going to Agile -> Manage Boards, clicking Configure for your board, selecting the General tab, and then clicking edit on the Saved Filter option. You can then modify the filter to include multiple projects by adding them to the projects dropdown (if using Basic view), or with JQL (if using the Advanced view) such as the following:

```
project in (PROJ1, PROJ2, PROJ3) ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

Having done that, save the filter and you should the see all of the corresponding issues on the board. If you do not have a "Save" button (but only "Save As"), the filter belongs to someone else and you cannot edit it. In that case, you can either:

1. ask the owner of the filter to make the changes for you, or
2. save the filter with a new name, and then go back to the Configure screen for the board, hover over the name of the old filter, click the Pencil icon, and then type in the name of your newly-saved filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can include tickets from as many projects as you like in a sprint. As mentioned in Scott's answer, this can be done by editing the filter used for that board. This filter doesn't have to specify what project a ticket is in, it just need to meet your filter's requirements.

So if you wanted to see all tickets from a project and any with a certain label you could change your filter to:

```
project in (proj1, proj2) or labels='component'
```

This will show all tickets that are in proj1, proj2, and tickets with the label component.

Keep in mind that if you do add tickets from a different project, your scrum lead or whomever ends the sprints will also need to be an administrator in that project.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Ending+a+Sprint

Here's Atlassian's documentation on JQL if you're interested in going deeper into filters
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching

Comment: Do you need to be an administrator merely because that resolves the tickets? (meaning, that won't be necessary if other project devs resolve their own tkt by hand)?

Comment: Also, your "here's" last sentence is missing a link (doesn't matter to me since I'm actually pretty experienced with JQL, just not with Agile stuff :)

Comment: I don't know the exact reasoning why they decided you had to be an administrator in the project. It doesn't matter if all the tickets are closed by hand, you still won't be able to close the ticket.
Even though their documentation says all tickets need to be closed to end a sprint, this is not true, all incomplete tickets will be put in the backlog.